# How to detect data update through REST or SOAP on a URL that I don't manage

Tags: xml, rest, soap, twilio

Can I easily detect a change at a certain URL with SOAP/REST where I don't control the URL in question?

In particular, I am trying to set up a [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com) Interface, and the data on their API page is different then the data that comes across when I receive a POST request on my side on my request URL for for my account.

I am thinking to make do with the data that they are sending to my request URL, but would rather detect any data changes on my twilio API URL on their side (their domain).

If my question isn't 100% clear, please let me know, and I can add detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It isn't clear. You want to detect a chance on someone's else API?

Comment: Yes, on the Twilio.com API.  I know that I can read from it, but I would have to schedule a chron job to do so periodically.  Instead, I would like to know each time the data changes on the `twilio.com/my_acccount/api/` page.

Comment: Unless they provide some sort of notification, that's the only way to do it.

Comment: That's what I was thinking.  Ok, thanks @PedroWerneck